# I would like to run a while loop inside a php query to submit address from textarea

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am working on a small project. I have a text area while I explode into lines using

```
$address_complete = $_POST['address'];
$address_array = explode("\n", $address_complete);
$address_count = count($address_array);
```

Now I know how many values coming from this array. Now I have built a query to insert into my database:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer SET ID = '$id',
                            Name = '$name',
                            Email = '$email',
                            Address1 = IF('$address_array[0]' = '', Address1, '$address_array[0]'),
                            Address2 = IF('$address_array[1]' = '', Address1, '$address_array[1]'),
                            Address3 = IF('$address_array[2]' = '', Address1, '$address_array[2]'),
                            Address4 = IF('$address_array[3]' = '', Address1, '$address_array[3]'),
                            Address5 = IF('$address_array[4]' = '', Address1, '$address_array[4]'),
                            City = '$city',
                            Country = '$country'";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Above working fine as long I have 5 values coming from the text area. But If I have less then I get error "Undefined offset:"

I thought of making a while loop inside query but I am still new to the awesome world of php so not really know. Did look around but can't find the right answer.

I am sure you guys can help but please remember I am new so easy language please :)

Thanks

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assumed that you have set default values to Address1,2,3,4 and 5 in case they are empty.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer SET ID = '$id',
                            Name = '$name',
                            Email = '$email',
                            City = '$city',
                            Country = '$country'";

for($i=0;$i<$address_count;$i++)
{
if($address_array[$i] != '')
$query .=", Address".($i+1)." = '$address_array[$i]'";
}

mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Comment: However, just before you replied I have managed to make it work on a more simpler way. Updating my question so it will benefit someone... Thank you

Comment: The edit is correct somehow, while the first code is wrong in two ways: first you aren't checking if isset, which will throw again undefined notice. Second you could do the same operation without doing copy to the code with for as you did in your edit. tl;dr, you should delete the first code

Comment: @Michael Arenzon Yes, my bad. Removed the flawed code.

Comment: Thank you both... It's working now... @MichaelArenzon Thanks for point that out and wishchaser thanks for updating it... COOL :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer SET ID = '$id',
                            Name = '$name',
                            Email = '$email',";
$addressQuery=""; 
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{

$addressQuery = $addressQuery + "Address'$i+1'=IF('$address_array[$i]' = '', Address'$i+1', '$address_array[$i]'),";
}
$query = $query + $addressQuery;
$query = $query + "City = '$city',
                   Country = '$country'";

mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it all makes sense however it's not working. $count isn't suppose to be $address_count?

Oh and I tried to echo the $query and it is only giving me 0. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Fix the assignment to generate the correct number of array items

```
$address_array = address_pad(explode("\n", $address_complete), 5, '');
```

Fix the query construction using the ternary operator and a loop

```
foreach($address_array as $index => $value) {
  $query .= ($value) ? " `Address{$index + 1}` = '{$value}'," : "";
}
```